# SQL Server : Joins, Duplicate Records and Union

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I'm joining tables, with the intent to produce a final table that has converted some rows to columns.  FK is a foreign key constraint, Info1 and Info2 are used to return either date or null

```
FK1 | Info1 | Date1
FK1 | Info2 | Date2
FK2 | Info1 | Date1
FK2 | Info2 | Date2
```

The table I want to return should look like this:

```
FK1 | Date1 | Date2
FK2 | Date1 | Date2
```

Instead, whats returning is:

```
FK1 | Date1 | Date2
FK1 | Date1 | Date2
FK2 | Date1 | Date2
FK2 | Date1 | Date2
```

After reading some other posts, it seems that I need UNION for this to work, but I can't figure out where to put it.  My actual query is below:

```
select c.idContract,
       c.sgCommonName,
       cl.sgClientTitle,
       cl.sgHomeAddress,
       cl.sgLetterCasual,
       c.sgLotAddress,
       ffd.sgCaption,
       ffv.sgTextValue,
       case when fkidffdefinition = 1161 then dtDateValue end as '11 Day',
       case when fkidffdefinition = 1162 then dtDateValue end as '30 Day'
from 
            tblContracts c
inner join  tblClients cl on cl.idClient = c.fkidClient
inner join  tblFlexFieldValues ffv on ffv.fkidcontract = c.idContract
inner join  tblFlexfieldDefinition ffd on ffd.idFlexFieldDefiniition = ffv.fkidFFDefinition 

where ffd.idFlexFieldDefiniition in (1161,1162)
```

The problem is that the joins are joining on these values `(1161,1162)`, but I don't understand how to "concatenate" the joins (if that makes sense)

Cheers.

Comment: Could you provide some actual data and desired results that match your actual query?

Comment: Use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to post an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow, I think this is the query that you want:

```
select c.idContract, c.sgCommonName, cl.sgClientTitle, cl.sgHomeAddress, cl.sgLetterCasual,
       c.sgLotAddress, ffd.sgCaption, ffv.sgTextValue,
       max(case when fkidffdefinition = 1161 then dtDateValue end) as "11 Day",
       max(case when fkidffdefinition = 1162 then dtDateValue end) as "30 Day"
from tblContracts c inner join
     tblClients cl
     on cl.idClient = c.fkidClient inner join
     tblFlexFieldValues ffv
     on ffv.fkidcontract = c.idContract inner join
     tblFlexfieldDefinition ffd
     on ffd.idFlexFieldDefiniition = ffv.fkidFFDefinition 
where ffd.idFlexFieldDefiniition in (1161, 1162)
group by c.idContract, c.sgCommonName, cl.sgClientTitle, cl.sgHomeAddress, cl.sgLetterCasual,
         c.sgLotAddress, ffd.sgCaption, ffv.sgTextValue;
```

This is an aggregation query, which will put the two dates on the same row.  By the way, it is a bad idea to use single quotes for column names.  Use double quotes or square braces instead.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

I had to remove the sgCaption field as it contained a different value to everything else and was enforcing the duplication.